# Web scraping number

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, text, beautifulsoup, request

```
import bs4, requests

url = requests.get(f'https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl?mod=over_search')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(url.text,'lxml')

print(soup.find("div",{"class": "intraday__data"}).find("h3",{"class": "intraday__price"}).find("bg-quote"))
```

Output:

```html
<bg-quote> channel="/zigman2/quotes/202934861/composite,/zigman2/quotes/202934861/lastsale" class="value" field="Last" format="0,0.00" session="pre">141.97</bg-quote>
```

It gives me an error when I type `.text` in the last of the last line and here is the error. I want to extract the price, any ideas?

```
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last) 

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(url.text,'lxml')
print(soup.find("div",{"class": "intraday__data"}).find("h3",{"class": "intraday__price"}).find("bg-quote")).text
 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 2):

You're typing `.text` after `print()` and `print` returns always `None`. Do this instead:

```py
print(
    soup.find("div", {"class": "intraday__data"})
    .find("h3", {"class": "intraday__price"})
    .find("bg-quote")
    .text
) # <-- NOT .text here!
```

Prints:

```
141.77
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    print(soup.select('.value')[6].text)


main('https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl?mod=over_search')
```

Output:

```
141.76
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl?mod=over_search"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text)

print(soup.select('.value')[6].text)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).